# How to replace/assign a block of data in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a data set called `test3` looking like (imported from excel):

```
$ID  $spec    $orient $direct   $rep     $slope   $intercept
9119    1       stance  15b     1       2859.09223  158
9119    2       stance  15b     2       2886.53583  321
9119    3       stance  0       1       2860.91423  21
9119    4       fall    15f     1       2878.9364   326
9119    5       fall    15f     2       2902.0397   45
9120    1       stance  15b     1       1444.91347  654
9120    2       stance  15b     2       1460.09585  23
9120    3       stance  0       1       1470.2588   85
9120    4       fall    15f     1       1481.6892   225
9120    5       fall    15f     2       1475.40215  145
```

and a template data frame called `test3mean`:

```
$ID  $spec    $orient $direct   $slope   $intercept
9119    1       stance  15b     nan     nan
9119    2       stance  0       nan     nan
9119    3       fall    15f     nan     nan
9120    1       stance  15b     nan     nan
9120    2       stance  0       nan     nan
9120    3       fall    15f     nan     nan
```

I am using Pandas dataframe to calculate the mean of the `$slope` and `$intercept` for repeated measurements in `test3` and put them in the corresponding columns in `test3mean`:

```
ID = np.array([9119,9120])
orient = np.array(['stance','fall'])
direct = np.array(['0','15f','15b'])

for i in ID:
    for o in orient:
        for d in direct:
            test3mean[test3mean['$ID']==i][test3mean['$orient']==o][test3mean['$direct']==d][['$slope','$intercept']] = test3[test3['$ID']==i][test3['$orient']==o][test3['$direct']==d][test3['$rep']!=3].mean()[['$slope','$intercept']]
```

However, the `test3mean` does not change. I am aware of the copy vs view issue, and have seen the `df.loc[:,()]` solutions, but was not able to implement them for my specific case.

The expected output after two steps of the loop would be for the test3mean to  look like:

```
$ID  $spec    $orient $direct   $slope       $intercept
9119    1       stance  15b     2872.81403  239.5
9119    2       stance  0       2860.91423  21
9119    3       fall    15f     nan     nan
9120    1       stance  15b     nan     nan
9120    2       stance  0       nan     nan
9120    3       fall    15f     nan     nan
```

Comment: can you provide an expected output

Comment: I think you need to reconsider and use `groupby` and `merge` to get desired result.  You are using index chaining which is a big "no no" in pandas due to the copy vs view issue.

Comment: @Kenan: I added an example output to the question.

Comment: @Scott: I understand that I should not use index chaining, but I was not able to apply the solutions I found to my case which has three __getitem__ commands and two columns (a block of 1X2 is to be replaced everytime). Could you provide a specific suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
result = (test3[test3['$rep'].ne(3)].groupby(['$ID','$orient','$direct'],as_index=False)['$slope','$intercept']
                                    .mean())

#    $ID $orient $direct       $slope  $intercept
#0  9119    fall     15f  2890.488050       185.5
#1  9119  stance       0  2860.914230        21.0
#2  9119  stance     15b  2872.814030       239.5
#3  9120    fall     15f  1478.545675       185.0
#4  9120  stance       0  1470.258800        85.0
#5  9120  stance     15b  1452.504660       338.5
```

---

If you need merge with `test3mean` use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `how ='left'`:

```
(test3mean.drop(['$slope','$intercept'],axis=1)
          .merge(result,on=['$ID','$orient','$direct'],how='left'))
```

**Output**

```
    $ID  $spec $orient $direct       $slope  $intercept
0  9119      1  stance     15b  2872.814030       239.5
1  9119      2  stance       0  2860.914230        21.0
2  9119      3    fall     15f  2890.488050       185.5
3  9120      1  stance     15b  1452.504660       338.5
4  9120      2  stance       0  1470.258800        85.0
5  9120      3    fall     15f  1478.545675       185.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast solution!

Comment: A small point remaining is my [test3['$rep']!=3] condition which is not included in this solution.

Comment: ups, check now. I am glad to help:)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this:

```
df.groupby(['$ID','$orient','$direct'], as_index=False)[['$slope','$intercept']].mean()
```

Output:

```
    $ID $orient $direct       $slope  $intercept
0  9119    fall     15f  2890.488050       185.5
1  9119  stance       0  2860.914230        21.0
2  9119  stance     15b  2872.814030       239.5
3  9120    fall     15f  1478.545675       185.0
4  9120  stance       0  1470.258800        85.0
5  9120  stance     15b  1452.504660       338.5
```

Comment: @ansev solution takes it to completion. :)

Comment: Thanks to both of you!

Comment: A small point remaining is my [test3['$rep']!=3] condition which is not included in this solution. Although not the case in the data I've shown here, it is an important condition in my actual dataset.